# MySQL / Searching Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables, 'photos' and 'videos'. Together they are almost identical, except one column, 'photoID' in 'photos' and 'videoID' in 'videos'.

When a user makes a search, I would like the video results to be mixed with the photo results, obviously from the same recordset.

How is it possible to do this using different column names? If it's not, do I change the column names to something like contentID, in both tables, and use a UNION to join them? It's a lot of work changing the columns but will have to if this isn't possible...

Comment: Why they're not in the same table, with a column do identify it's type (video/photo)? Yes, a Union can solve your problem, but it looks like your design is wrong

Comment: What are you using for search? MyISAM Fulltext? Sphinx? Solr? Straight LIKE queries?

Comment: you could make a union, that doesn't display photoID and videoID

Comment: @Cody Caughlan - I am using MyISAM full-text

Comment: @Andre - I chose to separate the two tables for performance, by the end of next year, the photos table will have 1,000,000+ rows, the videos table could be similar size. Plus, not all my users have permission to search both tables, so I give performance to the users that don't have this permission, only searching one table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to change the column names in the tables. Just use an alias on the `SELECT`. I'd go with a `UNION ALL` (more efficient than `UNION` as it won't try to eliminate dupes) and add an additional column to identify where the content came from.

```
SELECT photoID AS contentID, colA, colB, ..., 'photo' AS ContentType
    FROM photos
UNION ALL
SELECT videoID AS contentID, colA, colB, ..., 'video' AS ContentType
    FROM videos
```

Comment: Thank-you Joe, informative answer. I'm interested to find out how I can use the additional column as you suggested above. I have never seen this method before...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from
(
SELECT VideoID as MediaID, * FROM Videos
UNION
SELECT PhotoID as MediaID, * FROM Photos
) as T
WHERE MediaID = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

use something similar to

```
select photoID AS ContentID, col1, col2 FROM PHOTOS WHERE col1 =...
UNION
select videoID AS ContentID, col1, col2 FROM VIDEOS WHERE col1 =...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2, NULL videoID, photoID 
from photos
where criteria = 'criteria'

union all

select column1, column2, videoID, NULL photoID 
from videos
where criteria = 'criteria'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make a union without displaying photoID and videoID, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT column names from Videos 
UNION
SELECT column names from Photos
```